# How to set flags of g++ using cmake such that gprof can demangle?

Tags: g++, cmake, gprof, demangler

How do I set the gprof flags for the compiler and linker of GNU g++ in a CMakeLists.txt?

My current approach,

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -pg")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -pg")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO} -pg")
```

does not allow gprof to demangle the C++ functions. Any ideas? (I am using C++11)

Comment: All that is needed to demangle a function is the function name itself,  you can't add extra g++ flags to help AFAIK.

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491948/how-to-use-gprof-with-cmake There is an answer which does not involve modifying the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
SET(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS} -pg")
```

That must add flags to compile and link, and use after execute the program:

```
gprof ./my_exe
```

If you get an error like:

```
gmon.out: No such file or directory
```

That means that compilation didn't add profiling info propertly.

The series of events here is supposed to work as follows:

```
1º Compile code with -pg option
2º Link code with -pg option
3º Run program
4º Program generates gmon.out file
5º Run gprof
```